# Is there an easy way to make many notes, line graphs, and directions, to PSD's in PhotoShop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

I'm doing a mockup design of a webpage I'm building. Upon completion, it will serve as the front page of my hopefully successful website. I'm using Adobe Photoshop and I have the Creative Cloud secondary package. So maybe I'm not aware, but there might be a program by Adobe that serves as a development tool, rather than a visual design tool (As Photoshop is such).

When the front page is complete. It will come equipped with a login, and once logged in, most of the data will change. And some of the design. So instead of simply using Photoshop to design, and Microsoft Word to take notes on how it's going to function....

Is there a way to add notes, draw arrows, make diagrams, and edit as if it was a paused screen of a football game (Where the announcer draws circles and explains the play)? If there is, is it possible through Photoshop or will I need to open Adobe Edge or something? I'm not sure if it's another program altogether or not.

Comment: Based on what you're trying to accomplish, I'd save your artwork in the ubiquitous PDF format and use Adobe Acrobat to add notes, comments, lines, other shapes, etc.

Comment: Save as .pdf and open that in the Adobe Acrobat reader? I've never done this.. Thanks though, will give it a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered:

1. Using the "Note tool" under the Eyedropper well, you can add an unlimited number of post-it like notes, see the image below
2. Adding a new blank layer and drawing away anything on it you like and turn it off when you want to see the original artwork
3. Creating a duplicate copy of the document, adding notes as described in step 2 and as the original changes, making a new copy and transfer the notes layer to it

[image]